# when loading tempView empty string is shown as null

Tags: csv, apache-spark, testing, apache-spark-sql

I am running some tests in spark. For that I'm loading a csv file to compare my results against.

My etalon

```
;;NULL;2017-03-21
;;NULL;2017-03-21
;;NULL;2017-03-21
```

This is how I'm loading the file

```
spark.read.schema(Table.schema)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .option("nullValue", "NULL")
      .load(pathTable)
      .createTempView(param.TABLE)
```

This is my schema

```
  val fields = Seq(
    StructField("balance", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("status", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("status_date", DateType, nullable = true),
    StructField("time_key", StringType, nullable = true)
  )
  val schema = StructType(fields)
```

For some reason `balance` and `status` are loaded as NULL when they should be empty strings.

```
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|balance|status|status_date|  time_key|
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|   null|  null|       null|2017-03-21|
|   null|  null|       null|2017-03-21|
|   null|  null|       null|2017-03-21|
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
```

Why is that and how can I have it shown as empty string?

Comment: Which version of spark do you use?

Comment: @astro I am using spark 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be normal behaviour in Spark. See this article [Spark’s Treatment of Empty Strings and Blank Values in CSV Files](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/sparks-treatment-of-empty-strings-and-null-values-in-csv-files-80748893451f).

To fix it you could replace null values in string columns with empty string like this:

```
df.withColumn("balance", coalesce(col("balance"), lit(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a issue raised for this which resolved in 2.4

SPARK-17916

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that was happening, but

```
.na.fill("", Seq("balance", "status"))
```

helped replace the nulls.